# Powershell: How to pass reference of Array from Powershell to C# Function

Tags: c#, arrays, powershell, pass-by-reference

I'm stuck with passing reference of Array from Powershell to C# function which takes Out parameter as array.

My C# Project goes like this

```
namespace SAMPLEAPI
{

    public class TestFunction
    {
        public int a;

        public String b;
    }
    public class Sample
    {
        public int Test(out TestFunction[] tests)
        {
            tests = new TestFunction[2];
            tests[0].a = 1;
            tests[1].a = 2;
            tests[0].b = "dummy1";
            tests[1].b = "dummy2";
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I have compiled the above project to SAMPLEAPI.dll, and trying to call this function in Powershell

Powershell Script:

```
Import-Module .\SAMPLEAPI.dll
$testArray = [SAMPLEAPI.TestFunction[]]
$test = [SAMPLEAPI.Sample]::new()
$test.Test([ref] $testArray)
```

I'm getting the following exception

```
Exception calling "Test" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot convert the 
"SAMPLEAPI.TestFunction[]" value of type
"System.RuntimeType" to type "SAMPLE.TestFunction[]"."
At line:1 char:1
+ $test.Test([ref] $a)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSInvalidCastException
```

Comment: `$testArray = $null`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot load a dll file like that. You have to do like this:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(".\SAMPLEAPI.dll")
```

Then you can use all the methods:

```
[SAMPLEAPI.Sample]::new()
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Problem is not with loading the Dll as such..I'm able to access other methods of C#.. But it was a good suggestion though..
Exception is at the line

    $test.Test([ref] $testArray)